# Single query to get only newest entry of grouped redundant entries

Tags: mysql, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

A table `files` looks like:

```
id, file_name, vendor_id, created
1,  z.txt,     2,         2011
2,  z.txt,     2,         2011
3,  a.txt,     1,         2016
4,  a.txt,     1,         2016
5,  a.txt,     1,         2016
6,  b.txt,     1,         2015
7,  y.txt,     2,         2015
8,  x.txt,     2,         2014
```

There is an index on: `file_name`, `vendor_id` and `created`.

I want a list of the latest files (`newest_file`) of each `vendor_id` in a single query.

```
SELECT vendor_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(file_name ORDER BY created DESC), ',', 1) AS newest_file 
FROM files GROUP BY vendor_id
```

This query works perfect, but is very slow. Is there a faster alternative **in a single** query?

---

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `color` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vendor_id` (`vendor_id`),
  KEY `file_name` (`file_name`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: I suggest you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE files;` in the question.

Comment: [_Groupwise max_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/)

Answer (score 2):

The best index for this query would be on `(vendor_id, created, file_name)`, with this specific order on the indexed columns.

There are various other methods to rewrite this type of queries, without using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. There is even a tag, at SO and this site: [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).

One way to rewrite (needs the same index as above). It assumes that `(vendor_id, created)` is `UNIQUE` (ie. there are no two rows with same vendor and created) or it isn't unique and you want all the duplicate/tied results:

```
SELECT 
    v.vendor_id,
    f.file_name AS newest_file,
    f.created                    -- you can have this in the results as well
FROM 
    ( SELECT vendor_id           -- you can replace the "v" subquery with  
      FROM files                 -- a single "vendors" table,
      GROUP BY vendor_id         -- if there is one
    ) AS v
  JOIN files AS f
  ON  f.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
  AND f.created =
      ( SELECT fi.created
        FROM files AS fi
        WHERE fi.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
        ORDER BY fi.created DESC
        LIMIT 1
      ) ;
```

If `(vendor_id, created)` is not `UNIQUE` and/or you want just one row of the duplicates, change the joining condition to:

```
--  the query as it is
-- 
  JOIN files AS f
  ON  f.id =
      ( SELECT fi.id 
        FROM files AS fi
--
--  the query as it is
```

Comment: Did not knew about `greatest-n-per-group`, thanks!

Comment: This seems not to work. :-/ It runs, but I stopped it after certain amount of time...

Comment: When I add a `LIMIT 10` at the end I get 10 redundant results. It seems that the JOIN is too expensive in combination with the subquery that returns the `created`. (When I hard set `f.created = 2016` it's very fast but useless. I think the JOIN has to be reduced by `GROUP BY` but don't know where.

Comment: The table contains more (not redundant) data in additional columns. Thank you for your help and inputs. I did not (yet) add the tripple index, but I clearly see what you mean. The limit was a was for me to see if this works at all. I don't understand the `ON  f.id = ...`. Should that replace the `SELECT fi.created` subquery but still has `ORDER BY fi.created DESC` in it?

Comment: It's some GB. But "only" 50+ vendor ids.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46761/discussion-between-ypercube-and-powtac).